# Turn off attached server monitor on system startup

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

*Edited*

I have turned my older Macbook into a linux server installing **Ubuntu Server 22.04 TTL**. I only SSH into this system and would like to keep the monitor turned off.

The following command works only when I run it on the physical server and turns the monitor off (it doesn't work through SSH session though):

```bash
setterm -blank force
```

Then I can continue using the system through SSH with no issues. But of course if I reboot the system, monitor is back on and I can only turn it off through sessions on the physical server.

I created the following service script and saved it to `/etc/systemd/system/monitor-off.service`:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Turn off monitor on startup

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setterm -blank force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enabled it with `systemctl enable monitor-off`. But when I reboot, it still doesn't work.

Running `systemctl is-enabled monitor-off` returns `enabled`. But when I run `systemctl status monitor-off` it gives me the following:

```
× monitor-off.service - Turn off monitor on startup
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/monitor-off.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-01-20 22:40:58 UTC; 11min ago
    Process: 791 ExecStart=/usr/bin/setterm -blank force (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 791 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 2ms

Jan 20 22:40:58 server systemd[1]: Started Turn off monitor on startup.
Jan 20 22:40:58 server setterm[791]: setterm: $TERM is not defined.
Jan 20 22:40:58 server systemd[1]: monitor-off.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 20 22:40:58 server systemd[1]: monitor-off.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Since it says $TERM not defined I replaced `ExecStart=/usr/bin/setterm -blank force` with `ExecStart=/usr/bin/setterm -blank force --term linux` (linux is the $TERM for when I run a session on physical machine.), but still no luck.

I edited the [Service] section of the service config file to look like this:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment="TERM=linux"
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setterm -blank force
```

After restarting the services and rebooting the machine nothing happened on startup and the monitor is still on. The systemctl status gives me this:

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/monitor-off.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2023-01-21 12:44:43 CST; 44s ago
Process: 790 ExecStart=/usr/bin/setterm -blank force (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 790 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CPU: 3ms

Jan 21 12:44:43 server systemd[1]: Starting Turn off monitor on startup...
Jan 21 12:44:43 server systemd[1]: monitor-off.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 21 12:44:43 server systemd[1]: Finished Turn off monitor on startup.
```

Further, when I try to start the service manually through virtual console (not SSH) using `systemctl start monitor-off.service` it tells me `setterm: cannot force blank: Inapproproate ioctl for device`. This commands returns no error when I run it through SSH but still doesn't turn the monitor off.

Comment: You are not using a GUI on your Ubuntu Sever, right? I guess you are using the virtual consoles. (in my case TERM is set to `linux` with no GUI and is set to `xterm-256color` with a GUI)

Comment: Correct @EdgarMagallon there’s no GUI. The term is linux for sessions started directly on server machine and xterm-256color for when I ssh into it.

Comment: If you run the service `sudo systemctl start monitor-off.sevice` does it fail? I've tested that and was unable to run it via systemd service, not sure why

Comment: @EdgarMagallon when I run it using virtual console nothing happen and when I check `systemctl status monitor-off.service` it says `setterm: cannot force blank: Innapropriate ioctl for device`

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence in the DESCRIPTION section of the `setterm(1)` man page is:

> `setterm` writes to standard output a character string that will invoke the specified terminal capabilities.

When you are logged in on a virtual console, the standard output will be the `/dev/tty[0-9]*` device that matches the number of the virtual console you're using, and the command works as intended. Also the environment variable `TERM` needs to be set to `linux` or some other value whose definition includes the Linux virtual console's "monitor off" string.

When you are logged in over SSH, the standard output will be a PTY device associated with the SSH connection, and you'll end up effectively trying to turn off the display of the terminal emulation of your SSH client.

When you are running the `setterm` command as a systemd service, its standard output is not going to any TTY/PTY device, but into systemd's journal (by default). Outputting special character strings into the journal certainly should not have any special effects like turning off the local monitor.

Try adding these lines to the `[Service]` section of your `monitor-off.service`:

```
Environment="TERM=linux"
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty0
```

(`/dev/tty0` refers to the currently active virtual console, regardless of what its actual number is.)

You'll also want the service to be `Type=oneshot` instead of `Type=simple`. Because `setterm` will not remain running after outputting the "turn display off" terminal control string, `Type=simple` would cause systemd to mark the service as "failed" even if it had executed successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I applied it but still no luck. Please see the edits in my original question @telcoM.